# Rebasing branch1 with changes in master from branch2

Tags: git

I have two branches off `master`; `branch1` and `branch2`.  I have some changes made on `branch1` and have an active PR up for this.  I also have changes on `branch2` that have been reviewed and merged into `master` and the branch subsequently deleted.

I have updated my local `master` by doing a `git fetch -ap` and a `git pull` which brought down the changes made in `branch2`.  I now want to update `branch1` with these changes so that the only differences are the ones I have made on that branch. I tried `git checkout branch1` followed by `git rebase master`.

However, when I do a `git status` on `branch1` it says:

```
On branch branch1
Your branch and 'origin/branch1' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Doing a `git pull` here opens up a merge comment dialog.  But now when I look at my PR on `branch1` it now includes the changes from `branch2` as new changes.  What has happened here, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For this answer, I'm assuming you have `branch1` checked out. If not, do `git checkout branch1`.)

When you do `git rebase master`, you are rewriting the commits in `branch1`, since they now have a new parent. This is what your history might look like:

```
X--*--Y [master]
 \     \
  \     A'--B'--C' [branch1]  <--
   \                            | (git rebase master)
    A--B--C [origin/branch1] ----
```

where e.g. `A'` has the same contents as `A`, but a different commit hash, because its parent is `Y` instead of `X`.

Since the commits have changed, you will have to force-update `origin`. After you finish the rebase, you should do:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

However, since you already did a `git pull` post-rebase, you'll need to fix that first. Do e.g.:

```
git reset --hard C'
```

Or:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This will remove the merge commit from `branch1`, and you can force push as described above. First, to ensure your branch was reset properly, do:

```
git log --oneline --decorate master..HEAD
```

The output of that command should show all the commits that should be in `branch1`, and only those commits.

(Aside: if you do `git status` at this point, you might see some output like this:

```
On branch branch1
Your branch is behind 'origin/branch1' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

You can safely ignore this warning, since the one of those commits was the merge commit, and the other was the `1 different commit` from your original error message.)

As mentioned above, at this point you should do:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

And now the remote `branch1` will have the same commits as your local `branch1`.

---

Obligatory **warning**: Since a rebase rewrites history, this can be dangerous / disruptive for anyone else working on this branch. Be sure you clearly communicate what you have done with anyone you are collaborating with.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Scott.  Just to clarify, on what branch do I need to run the `git push --force-with-lease`?  I ran the reset on `branch1`.

Comment: `git status` on `branch1` now says

`On branch branch1
Your branch is behind 'origin/branch1' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)`

Comment: @MeanwhileInHell Updated my answer to address both comments.

Comment: Thanks so much for this Scott, worked perfectly.  This is something I continually run into, so your answer should put an end to that.